# How to add a global text attribute to all products

Tags: magento-1.9

We are using Magento Community Edition 1.9, and we struggle a little bit to make up a editable text area attribute for all our products.
Ex: we would like to setup a text for our return policy that customers could see on all of our product pages, that we could easily edit later in the future.

The issue might come from configurable products, since only attribute with scope "Global", input type "Dropdown" and Use To Create Configurable Product "Yes" are available. However, putting a text area would not qualify for that.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to Magento.SE! Great question. I wonder if you really need this on every product? Is the policy the same for all products? If so, you'll want a static block. Otherwise we can use a Text Area attribute type.

Here's how to add a text type attribute:

- Login to admin
- Go to `Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes`
- Press the `Add new attribute` button in the top right

From here you need to create a new attribute of type `Text Area`:

[image]

One field to take note of here is the `Product Type` field. If you'd like it to only display on configurable products, as you've noted, then you'll one to set it up like so:

[image]

Once you've filled in all the required details you need to add it to an attribute set. Adding it to the Default attribute set will not automatically add it to all products.

### A word on attribute sets

When a product is created, the first step is to choose an attribute set that defines it. This is a value that can never be altered. If you need to add this attribute to all attribute sets you will need to add it to all applicable attribute sets. If you would like it to only appear on shoes, for instance, then you want to add the attribute to the Shoes attribute set.

### Final thought

This will *not* necessarily show the contents of the attribute in your template or your theme unless your theme is coded to display all product attributes (doubtful).

I would suggest that you also look into the static block method, using a Magento Widget to display that static block somewhere in your product pages.

Best of luck!

Comment: i guess that `A word on attribute sets` is the main issue